# On click link popup javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want a pop up on a link on my website.
I want the pop having following code

```
<script data-cfasync=false src="//s.ato.mx/p.js#id=8135&type=popup&size=800x600&hourscap=1"></script>
```

and my link for example

```
`<a href="page.php">Click Me</a>`
```

I want when someone click on the click me link the pop up appears. also kindly tell me how can i add pop up on the scroll bar.

I am in learning stage. kindly guide me

Comment: What is this popup? If it's a third-party API, I'm sure thay have instructions on how to properly implement it.

Answer (score 0):

save the following code as `.html` or `.php` file without making any changes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>POPUP Demo</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(function(){ 
          $("#btn").click(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              var newWindow = window.open("", "newWindow", "width=700");
              newWindow.document.write("<p>content of popup window</p><code>echo '<b>echo php</b>';</code>");
          });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" id="btn">Click me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: not working. can u plz add me the popup code and update the code for me thanks. it will give me a better idea